# Tracing SQL queries created by Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In the web application I am currently developing, I have quite a few database queries being performed. I would like to know what parts of the code are producing these queries so that I can perhaps refactor the code to reduce them. Is there an easy way to do this?

Typically, the database queries are like:

`SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM 'stores' WHERE ('stores'.'distributor_id' = 1)`

Thanks very much for your suggestions!

Gav

Comment: which RDBMS are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using MySQL as my DBMS. I don't think the optimisations are required there (yet) since the time taken on these queries is usually 0.2ms (coming from cache, I expect?). I think I'm asking Rails to do something repeatedly which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [QueryTrace](http://terralien.com/projects/querytrace).

Answer (score 1):

To show the SQL of a query on a Ruby on Rails console just follow these steps:

```
if ENV.include?('RAILS_ENV') && !Object.const_defined?('RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER')
  require 'logger'
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end


path_to_project$ sc
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.7)
>> User.first
  User Load (0.8ms)   SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1
```